# Mosquitto TLS - Connection Refused: not authorised

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi3, mosquitto

I am trying to set up my Raspberry pi 3B as an mqtt server using Mosquitto. I am following this tutorial: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=287326

I have got half way down the page to: "Now that the certificates are in place, the subscription client can be invoked using them while pointed at the broker. The broker will be at 192.168.1.140 on the same LAN." Where I am trying to connect a subscriber via TLS, but the connection is refused with message "Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised."

I have used a private IP 192.168.2.215 for both the server and client. Is this possible?

My conf file are divided in two files:

authentication.conf:

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
```

encryption.conf:

```
listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/mosquitto-certificate-authority.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.crt
tls_version tlsv1.2
```

As far as I understand all the keys and certificates have been created. All the steps up until now have been successful.

The server is running I assume since a "systemctl status mosquitto " returns "...Started Mosquitto MQTT Broker" on the last line.

Here is my start up log:

```
1689408731: mosquitto version 2.0.11 terminating
1689408731: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1689408731: mosquitto version 2.0.11 starting
1689408731: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1689408731: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1689408731: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1689408731: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1689408731: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1689408731: mosquitto version 2.0.11 running
1689408760: New connection from 192.168.2.215:46250 on port 8883.
1689408760: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
```

The log is after running:

```
sudo mosquitto_sub -v -h 192.168.2.215 -u xxx -P 'yyy' --key /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt --cert /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.crt -t 'temperatures' -p 8883 --tls-version tlsv1.2 -i listener03

Unable to connect (A TLS error occurred.).
```

After adding -d to the client command I get this:

```
sudo mosquitto_sub -v -d -h 192.168.2.215 -u xxx -P 'yyy' --key /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt --cert /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.crt -t 'temperatures' -p 8883 --tls-version tlsv1.2 -i listener03 

In terminal:
Error: Unable to load client key file "/etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt".
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
OpenSSL Error[1]: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
Unable to connect (A TLS error occurred.).

Added to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.log:
1689518781: New connection from 192.168.2.215:45280 on port 8883.
1689518781: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
```

The listener03-client.crt file permissions are as follows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1099 14 jul 10.41 listener03-client.crt
```

Comment: You shouldn't seperate the `listener 8883` line from the entries that contain the cert/key information (and your files do not match the examples). Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76686452/edit) the question to show the mosquitto startup logs.

Comment: @hardillb I moved the listener 8883 to the conf-file with the cert/key paths. The error message changed from "Connection refused" to "TLS error occurred, as shown in the edited version of my original post.

Comment: Add `-d` to the client command to get more debug info.  Also did you say the right IP address for the broker on the SAN entry in the broker certificate?

Comment: My raspberry pi´s IP address is 192.168.2.215. I have used 192.168.2.215 for all server and client settings. For example:-extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=IP:192.168.2.215"). I am trying to connect the client from the same IP addres that the server is running on. Is this possible, or do I need to client-connect from another device on the same network? (end goal is to get this running over the Internet)

Comment: If I open the listener03-client.crt in TextEditor i get -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- .......16 rows of jibberish.......-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: However, if I try to double click listener03-client.crt or mqtt-server.crt from filehandler, the cursor just starts the time glass. Is this expected?

Comment: I have no idea what you have bound to the `crt` extension, but I wouldn't expect any meaningful GUI application to be liked to certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates != Keys

```
mosquitto_sub -v -d -h 192.168.2.215 -u xxx -P 'yyy' \
    --key /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt \
    --cert /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt \
    --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.crt \
    -t 'temperatures' -p 8883 --tls-version tlsv1.2 -i listener03
```

You have passed the same file for both the `--cert` and `--key` arguments. These files should be different things.

The key file should be the private key `listener03-client.key` not the `listener03-client.crt`

Comment: Thanx hardillb, I see that now. When I changed to --key /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.key this happened: sudo mosquitto_sub -v -d -h 192.168.2.215 -u xxx -P 'yyy' --key /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.key --cert /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.crt -t 'temperatures' -p 8883 --tls-version tlsv1.2 -i listener03
Client listener03 sending CONNECT
Client listener03 received CONNACK (5)
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
Client listener03 sending DISCONNECT

Comment: Then your username/password is incorrect or your client certificate is not signed by `/etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/mosquitto-certificate-authority.crt`

Answer (score 0):

#### Wrong username/password:

I successfully tested step 2 in the tutorial and double checked I had the same user/password for step 3 (TLS-client). Don´t think I got the wrong user/passwd.

#### Certificate not signed:

I recreated the listener03-client.crt file and signed the key successfully:

```
xxx@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto/certs $ sudo su -c 
'openssl x509 
-req 
-days 3650 
-CA /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/mosquitto-certificate-authority.crt 
-CAkey /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/mosquitto-certificate-authority.key 
-CAcreateserial 
-in listener03-client.csr 
-out listener03-client.crt 
-extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=IP:192.168.2.215")'
```

In terminal (where country code is something else):

```
Signature ok
subject=C = COUNTRY CODE, CN = 192.168.2.215
Getting CA Private Key
Enter pass phrase for /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/mosquitto-certificate-authority.key:
xxx@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto/certs $
```

And trying to connect a client:

```
sudo mosquitto_sub -v -d 
-h 192.168.2.215 
-u xxx -P 'yyy' 
--key /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.key 
--cert /etc/mosquitto/certs/listener03-client.crt 
--cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.crt -t 'temperatures' -p 8883 
--tls-version tlsv1.2 -i listener03 

Client listener03 sending CONNECT
Client listener03 received CONNACK (5)
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
Client listener03 sending DISCONNECT
```

I understand that the CONNACK from the server is not accepting my client to connect. I will reinstall everything from scratch on the Raspberry Pi and get back with results, may be a while.